# angular build error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am suddenly facing build fail error for production.
I am running this command:

```
ng build --prod
```

and getting following error:

```
D:\a\1\s\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\input-source-map-

tracker.js:37
  if (originalPosition.line === null && line > 1 && selectorFallbacks > 0) {
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of undefined
    at originalPositionFor (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\input-source-map-tracker.js:37:23)
    at originalMetadata (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\clean-css\lib\tokenizer\tokenize.js:486:43)
    at intoTokens (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\clean-css\lib\tokenizer\tokenize.js:435:68)
    at tokenize (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\clean-css\lib\tokenizer\tokenize.js:74:10)
    at fromStyles (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\read-sources.js:147:12)
    at fromString (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\read-sources.js:48:10)
    at doReadSources (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\read-sources.js:33:12)
    at readSources (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\read-sources.js:24:10)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\clean-css\lib\clean.js:99:12
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
Error: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe failed with return code: 1
```

It used to work fine a few days ago but suddenly stopped working.
Does any body have idea that why is this happening?

(I am using angular cli version 1.6.7)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of `clean-css` do you have installed? And which version was working for you?

Comment: if it helps, remove the `^` from your package.json. So you keep the version that actually worked for you, Expample: `clean-css: x.x.x` instead of `clean-css: ^x.x.x`.

Comment: I am not using clean-css at all. angular cli's dependencies are depending on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 : ng build -- prod fails due to clean-css : Cannot read property 'line' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033898/angular-5-ng-build-prod-fails-due-to-clean-css-cannot-read-property-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! It's confirmed that this is happening in latest version of angular cli.

I finally fixed my issue by lowering version to 1.6.7 and by removing ^
I was facing this issue even after lowering version:

"@angular/cli": "^1.6.7"

Then I removed ^ to fix the cli version and now it works fine.

I request angular team that please fix this angular cli issue so that we can use latest versions.

I hope this would help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. But when I build using `ng build --env=prod` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

While it seems clean-css is failing fantastically after @angular/cli 1.6.7, this issue can be resolved for later versions of @angular/cli, regardless.

I got a lead on this issue being caused by non-breaking spaces: https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/issues/1006

I was then able to resolve the issue by opening the src/ folder as a workspace in Notepad++, filtering on *.scss and *.css, and doing a search with Regex on using `\xA0` to find non-breaking spaces in the scss/css files; I found one. Once removed, my error went away.

Answer (score -1):

Issue got resolved

ng build --env=prod
solves the problem no need to downgrade angular cli version